# How to place ELF sections using the GNU linker at addresses according to their name?

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, linker-scripts

I'm trying to put together a GNU linker script that places two types of sections:

- the normal sections at fixed and predefined addresses. `.text` at `0x100000`, `.data` at `0x200000`, `.bss` at `0x300000` and so on
- special sections according to their name. for example `__at_0x13370000` should be placed at address `0x13370000`

the first type is trivial and is explained everywhere. no problem there.

the issue that I have is with the second type. I can't figure out how to process a section's name to turn it into the address at which it is placed. the `__at_` prefix used in the example above could be chosen freely.

I was previously using the ARM RVCT linker (`armlink`) where any section named in the schema of `.ARM.__at_xxxxxx` (where `xxxxxx` is a decimal or hexadecimal value) was placed at the corresponding address.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0803e/pge1362066000571.html

I would like to switch to the GCC toolchain and the GNU linker, but in order for that to be possible, I need to somehow replicate this behaviour.

Thanks

Comment: You can use many tools to pipe/transform to create code for the linker script.  For instance, `readelf -S` on input elf file can find all of the `__at_XXXX` sections.  Use tools like `grep`, `sed`, `python`, `perl` or plain `sh` to transform the list collected into linker parseable text.  Then use the [`INCLUDE filename`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/File-Commands.html) in your main linker script (with `.text`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract section addresses from object files before linking and generate a small addend for linker script:

```
readelf -t *.o \
  | grep -o '^ *\[ *[0-9]\+\] \.[a-zA-Z_0-9]\+_at_[x0-9]\+' \
  | sed 's!.*\(\..*\)_at_\([x0-9]\+\).*!\1_at_\2 \2!' \
  | sort -u \
  | while read name addr; do
    cat <<EOF
$name $addr:
{
  KEEP(*($name)) ;
}
EOF
  done > fixed.lds
```

`fixed.lds` can now be `INCLUDE`d into main linker script.